# Exception thrown in NPOI while opening a file, but only in release mode

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, exception, npoi

I just made a class that can translate an Excel file into a list of C# objects. I am currently working on Xamarin.Android.
All worked fine in debug mode, the file was opening correctly.
But when I changed to release mode, it just crashes without any exception message, but only the stacktrace (that I don't understand :s)

I believe my permissions are correctly setup, I checked them in the application settings.

I tried with a Windows application, it works.

I tried to change the file's location, but nothing changed.

```
try
{
     book = new XSSFWorkbook(filePath.GetStream());
}
catch (Exception e) // Exception without message
{
    onResult(new SyncProductsSummary(false, 0, 0, e));
    return;
}
```

filePath.GetStream works just fine, I get the actual file size, and I also tried NOT using this, but by giving the filePath as string, nothing changed.

Here's the stacktrace I get:
[image: stacktrace]

If the image doesn't work (I'm not sure how to use this):
https://pasteboard.co/IgbV96W.jpg

Comment: try changing the linker settings for Release mode to "Don't LInk" or "Link Framework Only"

Comment: @Jason It worked changing the Link method to "dont link", but my APK is not 61Mo. I guess I should look into the answer below. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is working in the debug configuration, but not the release configuration, it is likely due to the linker settings. Like [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason) mentioned, your release configuration may be trying to "Link All" which would require linker configuration for use. Try using one of the other two settings.

- MS Android Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker
- MS iOS Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker

If you are unfamiliar, you can find these settings in your project build settings.

[image: Xamarin Android Project Linker Settings]